# Определение номера COM-порта в int в C#

Tags: c#

Только осваиваю C#. Есть задача получить конкретно номер Com-порта в int, а не как обычно в string , например не "COM10", а 10.
Конкретнее: в windows forms

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    cBoxComPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
}
```

Получаю список портов в выпадающем списке. Затем, используя cBoxComPort.Text получаю то, что было выбрано из портов, но, естественно в string, а для моей задачи нужно получить после выбора из списка конкретно номер порта.

Comment: Видимо, нужно извлечь из строки то, что идёт после "COM". Если там ещё что-то есть, кроме номера - то до первой не-цифры. И перевести в число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxComPort.Text.Substring(3));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Отличное рабочее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Думал, может есть какой простой вариант, пока сделал такую затычку:

```
int addr = 0;
                switch (cBoxComPort.Text.Length)
                {
                    case 4:
                        addr = cBoxComPort.Text[3] - '0';
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        addr = (cBoxComPort.Text[3] - '0') * 10 + (cBoxComPort.Text[4] - '0');
                        break;
                }
```